# How can I organize 2 divs within a main div to be always stationary?

Tags: html, css, alignment, wrapper

I would like to create a div (within a main wrapper for a website) to contain 2 div to fill in the previously mentioned div. I have actually done this already....but my problem is that the 2 smaller divs dont align nor stay fixed in the main div. How is this even possible if they are confined to a main div?

Here is what I have done so far and there this issue is present: http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/17/

The text and the map (both with black borders) should be in the red box (which is the main div) and shouldnt move under no circumstances.

Comment: add some colour to each of the divs its kind of hard to tell

Comment: it is basically the map and the address....those are the 2 small divs. The red box is the main div.

Comment: but still if u colourize it helpers will identify the problem at a glance

Comment: done. used black for the 2 sub-divs and the main is the red one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sizing is a little off. (`#column1` (300px) + `#column2` (900px) = 1200px not 1198). Use [`box-sizing:border-box;`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) to make it easier

```
#container {    
    width:1200px;
    ...
}    
#column1 {
    width:300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    ...
}    
#column2 {
    width:900px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    ...
}
```

http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/18/

Comment: you beat me by few seconds, Same way I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to `float` the inner divs.

Because `div` elements display as `block` they won't follow each other horizontally in-line. Using float will put them next to one another.

Don't forget to account for the border width of each inner element so they fit inside the wrapper. In the below example the larger div has a width of 646px instead of 650px because 4px were used for the right and left border of the inner div's combined.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="small-div"></div>
    <div id="large-div"></div>
</div>

#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#small-div, #large-div{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#small-div{
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}
#large-div{
    width: 646px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g9Hn3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your divs have fixed width and height. Your container is 1198px wide, while your inner divs sum up 1200px, thus wrapping as they don't fit in their parent's 1198px width.

Answer (score 0):

Give both your divs "display: inline-block". This will make them line up side by side as long as their width is not greater than that of the red box.

```
#text{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;

#map{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 69%;
}
```